# SQL select with Unicode

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

I have database with encoding UTF-8, collation and ctype ru_RU.UTF-8. Table structure - `id`, `key`, `value`. One line inserted:

```
1 | size | --- "\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB7\xD0\xBC\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80"|
```

When I executed

```
SELECT E'--- "\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB7\xD0\xBC\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80"';
```

in console, I got the correct output

```
   ?column?   
   --------------
    --- "Размер"
   (1 row)
```

But when I tried to execute

```
select "value" from "translations" where "key"='size';
```

I got

```
   value                          
   --------------------------------------------------------
    --- "\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB7\xD0\xBC\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80"
   (1 row)
```

How do I get the unescaped string?

```
CREATE TABLE translations (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "key" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    "value" text,
    CONSTRAINT translations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) )
 WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
 ALTER TABLE translations OWNER TO user;
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_translations_on_key ON translations USING btree (key);
```

Comment: why not show DDL of CREATE TABLE?

Comment: CREATE TABLE translations
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "key" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  "value" text,
  CONSTRAINT translations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE translations OWNER TO user;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_translations_on_key
  ON translations
  USING btree
  (key);

Comment: found function quote_literal, it gives output - E'--- "\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB7\xD0\xBC\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80"', but don't know how to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval(text) RETURNS text AS
$BODY$  
DECLARE
  s text;
  r text;
BEGIN
  s := 'select ' || $1 ;
  execute s into r;
  return r;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

select eval(E'E\'' || "value" || E'\'') from translations where key = 'size' and "value" IS NOT NULL;
```

looks awful, but works :)

Comment: obligatory "zomg that's so ugly" remark. ugly solutions for ugly data :p

Comment: true that, but this is not my data and i have to work with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you store escaped values in the database, but as far as I can tell, the decode function should do what you want.

```
SELECT decode(value, 'hex')
FROM translations;
```

Comment: decode not working. i tried. it fails on first '-' symbols. this is not me stored those values :)